# Bullied by the EventKit framework on iOS 6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, eventkit

At first I though I had left my self this message, but then I started seeing more comments like this one. I just want to ask if Im the only one seeing messages like this ? I think its funny in some way, but it left me wondering if I'd got a rogue SDK

```
 2012-11-10 13:15:53.736 myApp[1419:907] *** -[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:]: date cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil date?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.
```

Comment: I can see why you were wondering.  It's actually much more informative than the average SDK error.

Comment: Yep I've gotten it as well. Some humorous programmer :-)

Comment: Just discovered this. I was a bit taken aback but certainly put a smile on my face - I've learnt my lesson now thanks Apple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the only one who has seen this. That's an official SDK message; programmer who wants to tell you what you're doing wrong, straight! You're safe to continue.